# How do I read a variable content from file file and increment it

Tags: bash

I'm writing an basic bash script where I'm reading a file which contains initially "1" as content.
After reading it I want to increase it +1 everytime whenever I run the script.

Example file: 1.txt:

```
1
```

Initial Content: 1

Expected output when run first time: 1.txt:

```
2
```

Here is my script:

```bash
#!/misc/acc-archive/util/bash
i=$(<1.txt)
echo "$1"
j=$((i+=1))
echo "$1"
find . -exec perl -pi -e 's/$1/$j/g' 1.txt \;
```

Comment: Notice that there is a race condition.  If multiple  instances of the script run, it is entirely possible that the content of the file will not increment correctly.  (eg, you read 4, the other process also reads 4, and then both processes increment to 5). If this matters, you need to work a bit more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You made a few mistakes. Here is a working copy:

```
i=$(cat 1.txt)

echo "i: $i"

j=$((i+=1))

echo "j: $j"
echo "$j" > 1.txt
```

I changed:

- $1 to $i
- switched from < to cat
- replaced the find/perl combination with just a >

Answer (score 2):

If you're replacing the entire contents of the file:

```
#!/bin/bash

i=$(<1.txt)
echo "$((++i))" > 1.txt
```

If you need to edit numbers in place in multiple files, you should provide more specific details about your task.